# StatusBar Text/Background updates don't work reliably

Tags: wpf, statusbar

New to WPF, trying to figure out why my style changes for a StatusBar aren't working reliably. Code seems very straightforward:

```
private void OnTryP4Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        statusText.Text = string.Format("Connecting to {0} as '{1}'.",
                                         textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text); // <-- Doesn't work
        statusBar.Background = Brushes.Yellow; // <-- Doesn't work

        if (m_Manager.P4Login(textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text,
            textBoxClientSpec.Text, passwordBox.Password))
        {
            statusText.Text = "SUCCESS!"; // <-- Doesn't work
            statusBar.Background = Brushes.Green; // <-- Doesn't work
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar.Background = Brushes.Red; // <-- THIS works
            statusText.Text = "Error connecting to Perforce server!"; // <-- THIS works
            buttonConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            buttonOK.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Can somebody show me the error in my ways?

The relevant XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfClient.P4LoginDialog"
    [...]
    Icon="feat.ico">
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="158">
    [...]
    <Button x:Name="buttonConnect" Content="Connect" Click="OnTryP4Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,130,0,-18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
    <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" Height="25" Background="#888" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="statusText"
                Width="Auto" 
                Height="Auto" 
                Foreground="#fff" 
                Text="Connect to P4 for live integration" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                TextAlignment="Right"
                />
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

**Update**: Thanks to these suggestions, I've been able to get the yellow text to work by doing the below. Still no luck with the green Success message. I got a whole bunch of reading on async to do to fully understand the execution flow and what the suggestions fully mean (last time I did anything like this, BackgroundWorkers were all the rage). I appreciate any other hints/explanations.

```
private async void OnTryP4Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        statusText.Text = string.Format("Connecting to {0} as '{1}'.",
                          textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text); // <-- Works now
        statusBar.Background = Brushes.DarkGoldenrod; // <-- Works now

        Task<bool> getConnection = m_Manager.P4Login(textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text, textBoxClientSpec.Text, passwordBox.Password);
        bool connection = await getConnection;

        if (connection)
        {
            statusText.Text = "SUCCESS!"; // <-- Still doesn't work (stays DarkGoldenrod)
            statusBar.Background = Brushes.Green; // <-- Still doesn't work (stays DarkGoldenrod)
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            statusBar.Background = Brushes.Red; // <-- Still works
            statusText.Text = "Error connecting to Perforce server!"; // <-- Still works
            buttonConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            buttonOK.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

public async Task<bool> P4Login(string uri, string user, string clientSpec, string password)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return m_PI.Connect(uri, user, clientSpec, password);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you attach the event handler `OnTryP4Login`?

Comment: How do your your code know that when  `OnTryP4Login` event needs to be fired ?

Comment: Added to the main post: 
<Button x:Name="buttonConnect" Content="Connect" Click="OnTryP4Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,130,0,-18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

The code fires for sure, and sometimes (on a failed connect) correctly gets to the Else {} statement.

Comment: Probably the method `P4Login` returns so fast, that you don't see the yellow color?

Comment: I got Thread.Sleep() everywhere to make sure things don't go too fast. You'll also see a 2 second wait in the code above, during which time the green status bar should be visible.

Comment: It's your Close method which is called right in the eventhandler, so the UI thread doesn't get time to update the changes. I bet if you remove the Close method (just for sake of testing), it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single-threaded application, updates to controls are not going to have an effect until your event handler is done and the screen can be updated.  Your `Thread.Sleep(2000);` blocks up the whole UI.

Make the method `async` and replace the sleep with `await Task.Delay( 2000 )`. This will allow the normal event loop to take over during those two seconds and the UI will get updated.

**Edit:** Your "Connecting" and yellow background still aren't going to work because (I assume) `m_Manager.P4Login()` is a synchronous function. If you can't make it async, do this right before calling it:

```
await Dispatcher.Yield( DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle );
```

This lets the event loop briefly take over and process all outstanding events (including your text and background color update) before your code continues.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the whole code runs in the GUI thread and prevents WPF from updating the GUI.

Try this one:

```
private async void OnTryP4Login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    statusText.Text = string.Format("Connecting to {0} as '{1}'.",
                                     textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text); // <-- Doesn't work
    statusBar.Background = Brushes.Yellow; // <-- Doesn't work

    await Task.Delay(100);

    if (m_Manager.P4Login(textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text,
        textBoxClientSpec.Text, passwordBox.Password))
    {
        statusText.Text = "SUCCESS!"; // <-- Doesn't work
        statusBar.Background = Brushes.Green; // <-- Doesn't work
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        statusBar.Background = Brushes.Red; // <-- THIS works
        statusText.Text = "Error connecting to Perforce server!"; // <-- THIS works
        buttonConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        buttonOK.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

If that worked, you should probably run the actual login asyncron like that:

```
var loginSucceeded = await Task.Run(() => m_Manager.P4Login(textBoxUri.Text, textBoxUser.Text,
        textBoxClientSpec.Text, passwordBox.Password));
```

instead of using `Task.Delay(100)`.